# Changing the Tag Manager code on a site with a new one erases the previous data?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Following the change of management of a site, I need to change the code relating to the **Tag Manager of this site with a new one**. I was wondering if, once this is changed, the data relating to the **period prior to the code change will be available** or only those relating to the new code will be visible. I looked for references on the Google FAQ, but didn't find much about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Tag Manager container changes doesn't affect the data that's already in Google Analytics. If you were to replace the GTM container ID on a website with another one, the GA data prior to the change will be there and any new data coming into GA from GTM will be set by the new container.